# Rails JSON callback - Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Im using thinking sphinx and it has become necessary to pull out the search results as JSON array with callback (JSONP). In my other functions like show, adding .json?callback=asd to the url allows this. But not for what i have retrieved with thinking_sphinx.  This is what my index looks like

```
def index
  @profiles = Profile.search params[:search], :match_mode => :any
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @profiles, :callback => params[:callback] }
  end
end
```

Ive been able to say /profiles.json?search=what to get a json. But how do i get a callback
What kind of url do i need to send, or other change i need to make, to get the right format for my models -- wrapperFunction(arrayOfJSONs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the callback as another query parameter:

```
/profiles.json?search=<query>&callback=<callbackname>
```

Just substitute `<query>` and `<callbackname>` with your values.